# Issue when Opening a usercontrol from one usercontrol on button click - c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, user-controls, buttonclick

I have a few UserControls on my C# Windows Form application on clicking of a button on the mainform it wll dock itself to the area on my mainform.

The first usercontrol (IncomeUC) is docked in a panel (panelContainer) on my MainForm when the Income button on my MainForm is clicked. 
[MainForm with The income usercontrol image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr331.png)

This UC contains a button (Add Income) which once clicked opens the next usercontrol (AddIncomeUC).

[Add income user control loaded after button click - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNYzy.png)

But once the AddIncomeUC is opened When i click on the Income button on my Main form to view the IncomeUC (or even if i click any other button to view other main UCs) it is not visible and the AddIncomeUC stays visible.

Is there away to fix this issue???

This is how the incomeUC is opened on the main form

```
    private void btnIncome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //when click the income button open the income records view
        //incomeUC1.BringToFront();

        this.panelContainer.Controls.Remove(dashboardUC1);
        this.panelContainer.Controls.Remove(expenseUC1);
        this.panelContainer.Controls.Remove(payerPayeeUC1);
        this.panelContainer.Controls.Remove(reportsUC1);
        this.panelContainer.Controls.Remove(predictionUC1);

        this.panelContainer.Controls.Add(incomeUC1);
        lblViewTitle.Text = "Your Income";
    }
```

this is how the AddIncomeUC is opened when click the add income button on the IncomeUC

```
public partial class IncomeUC : UserControl
{
    AddIncomeUC addIncomeUC1;
    public IncomeUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        addIncomeUC1 = new AddIncomeUC();
    }

    private void btnAddIncome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        this.Parent.Controls.Add(addIncomeUC1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is only one control at the time opened?

Comment: @J.vanLangen i did not follow what you meant? on the main form when i click on the income button the income UC is docked on the main form. And that UC has a button which opens another UC.

Comment: when you open the another UC the previous is removed? or stacked?